# Device rebooting when i click any EditText on login and sign-up screen

Tags: java, android

Every time I click the password or email EditText to type something, a few seconds pass and my phone starts rebooting

**I have tried the following:**

- Making a new Android Studio project and puting the code there to see if the problem is with the project libraries
- Re-making the login layout but again i have the same problem
- Removing some part of my code like `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method etc
- I searched for a similar problem to mine on google but did not find anything useful
- Changing the layout name from **activity_main** to **activity_login**
- Removing the `onCreate` method and running the activity without it

**LoginActivity.java:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final EditText email = findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final Button login_btn = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        final ProgressBar loading_bar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final TextView signup = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        final TextView reset_password = findViewById(R.id.textView38);

        loading_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        reset_password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PasswordResetActivity.class));
            }
        });

        login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loading_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String email_input = email.getText().toString();
                String password_input = password.getText().toString();

                if (email_input.isEmpty() || password_input.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please fill all the values!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loading_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email_input, password_input).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (email_input.isEmpty() || password_input.isEmpty()){
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please fill all the values!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    // user has logged in successfully \\
                                    finish();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, 
HomeActivity.class));
                                }else{
                                    // user is not logged in \\
                                    loading_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong email or password. 
Please check your information and try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
        }
    });

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView38"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Reset your password"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="181dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="614dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19999999" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Sign in to your SM account to laugh as much as you want for free"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/username"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="266dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_style"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="email address"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="266dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_style"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="password"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/default_btn_style"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            android:text="Sign in to SM account"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:text="new to social meme?"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="create an account"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/centerDark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/loading_icon_style"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.909" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.george.socialmeme">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SocialMeme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivityT"/>
    <activity android:name=".FeedbackActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".PasswordResetActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".BugReportActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChangePasswordActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SecurityActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChangeEmailActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChangeUsernameActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AccountInformationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".UploadPostActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SignupActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**My logcat:**

```
2021-03-04 21:15:31.328 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/ViewRootImpl@f8a674d[LoginActivityT]: 
ViewPostIme pointer 0
2021-03-04 21:15:31.424 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/ViewRootImpl@f8a674d[LoginActivityT]: 
ViewPostIme pointer 1
2021-03-04 21:15:31.455 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/Toast: show: focusDisplayId = 0, 
isFocusInDesktop = false mCustomDisplayId=-1
2021-03-04 21:15:31.465 12812-25564/com.george.socialmeme V/Toast: SHOW: 
android.widget.Toast$TN@1a4c799
2021-03-04 21:15:31.468 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme V/Toast: HANDLE SHOW: 
android.widget.Toast$TN@1a4c799 mView=null mNextView=android.widget.LinearLayout{14fca5e V.E...... 
......I. 0,0-0,0}
2021-03-04 21:15:31.468 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme V/Toast: HANDLE HIDE: 
android.widget.Toast$TN@1a4c799 mView=null
2021-03-04 21:15:31.481 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/ViewRootImpl@cf14455[Toast]: setView = 
android.widget.LinearLayout@14fca5e TM=true MM=false
2021-03-04 21:15:31.481 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme V/Toast: Text: Qlea in 
android.widget.Toast$TN@1a4c799
2021-03-04 21:15:31.493 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/ViewRootImpl@cf14455[Toast]: Relayout 
returned: old=(0,79,1080,2274) new=(283,1990,797,2106) req=(514,116)0 dur=7 res=0x7 s={true 
480379101184} ch=true
2021-03-04 21:15:31.495 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/OpenGLRenderer: createReliableSurface : 
0x6fd8bf6f40(0x6fd8d36000)
2021-03-04 21:15:31.495 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/Surface: 
Surface::connect(this=0x6fd8d36000,api=1)
2021-03-04 21:15:31.496 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/mali_winsys: EGLint 
new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, 
EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2021-03-04 21:15:31.496 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface : 
0x6fd9c5e000
2021-03-04 21:15:31.496 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/Surface: 
Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x6fd8d36000,bufferCount=3)
2021-03-04 21:15:31.496 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/Surface: 
Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x6fd8d36000)
2021-03-04 21:15:31.499 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/OpenGLRenderer: makeCurrent EglSurface : 
0x6fd9c5e700 -> 0x6fd9c5e000
2021-03-04 21:15:31.522 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/OpenGLRenderer: makeCurrent EglSurface : 
0x6fd9c5e000 -> 0x6fd9c5e700
2021-03-04 21:15:31.537 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/ViewRootImpl@cf14455[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED: 
frame=(283,1990,797,2106) ci=(0,0,0,0) vi=(0,0,514,116) or=1
2021-03-04 21:15:33.466 12812-25564/com.george.socialmeme V/Toast: HIDE: 
android.widget.Toast$TN@1a4c799
2021-03-04 21:15:33.467 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme V/Toast: HANDLE HIDE: 
android.widget.Toast$TN@1a4c799 mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{14fca5e V.E...... ........ 0,0- 
514,116}
2021-03-04 21:15:33.467 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme V/Toast: REMOVE! 
android.widget.LinearLayout{14fca5e V.E...... ........ 0,0-514,116} in 
android.widget.Toast$TN@1a4c799
2021-03-04 21:15:33.472 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/OpenGLRenderer: destroyEglSurface : 
0x6fd9c5e000
2021-03-04 21:15:33.474 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/Surface: 
Surface::disconnect(this=0x6fd8d36000,api=1)
2021-03-04 21:15:33.476 12812-25565/com.george.socialmeme D/OpenGLRenderer: ~ReliableSurface : 
0x6fd8bf6f40
2021-03-04 21:15:33.477 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/ViewRootImpl@cf14455[Toast]: 
dispatchDetachedFromWindow
2021-03-04 21:15:33.488 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 
'30571db', fd=99
2021-03-04 21:15:41.261 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/ViewRootImpl@f8a674d[LoginActivityT]: 
ViewPostIme pointer 0
2021-03-04 21:15:41.321 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/ViewRootImpl@f8a674d[LoginActivityT]: 
ViewPostIme pointer 1
2021-03-04 21:15:41.339 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/InputMethodManager: 
prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@258009f[LoginActivityT]
2021-03-04 21:15:41.339 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/InputMethodManager: 
getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2021-03-04 21:15:41.339 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: 
tba=com.george.socialmeme ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@c90f52f 
mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2021-03-04 21:15:41.339 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id 
: 0
2021-03-04 21:15:41.349 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - 
mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2021-03-04 21:15:41.353 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 
'ClientS', fd=95
2021-03-04 21:15:41.353 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/InputMethodManager: SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 
12812 view : com.george.socialmeme
2021-03-04 21:15:41.353 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/InputMethodManager: 
prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@258009f[LoginActivityT]
2021-03-04 21:15:41.353 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/InputMethodManager: 
getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2021-03-04 21:15:41.358 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/Editor: waiting for the right moment
2021-03-04 21:15:41.368 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist 
data: 2276 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views
2021-03-04 21:15:41.432 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/ViewRootImpl@f8a674d[LoginActivityT]: 
MSG_RESIZED: frame=(0,0,1080,2400) ci=(0,79,0,867) vi=(0,79,0,867) or=1
2021-03-04 21:15:41.471 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme I/ViewRootImpl@f8a674d[LoginActivityT]: 
Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=16 res=0x1 s={true 
480395943936} ch=false
2021-03-04 21:15:41.479 12812-12812/com.george.socialmeme D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed
```

Comment: When you say rebooting, you mean the phone is fully shutting down? That sounds very unusual!

Comment: @HenryTwist yes

Comment: Have you tried running the activity without your `onCreate` code and then adding it back in line by line? Then we can diagnose where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @HenryTwist I try it but again my phone is restarting, you can help me?

Comment: Just to clarify, you've started `LoginActivity` from another activity, with no code in `onCreate` apart from `super` and `setContentView`. Then no errors occur until you touch an `EditText` which causes the phone to reboot?

Comment: @HenryTwist Yes, i have the same problem if i try this and also i don't have any errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229558/discussion-between-henry-twist-and-george-sepetadelis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the whole code on different devices, physical and emulated and there seems to be no problems. Seems like it is an issue with your particular device, probably unrelated to your code.

Answer (score -1):

I copied the code and it works fine for me, it's clearly not from the code